# Avoiding fetch in Jooq subquery

Tags: mysql, jooq

I need to select a "page" of data from a very large table. Because of the WHERE clause and the need to page into rather large offsets, I am using a subquery to fetch the IDs. This strategy only works if I put `fetch` on the end. This results (I think) in an extra round-trip to the database. Is there any way to avoid the extra `fetch`?

```
final Object subquery =
    JooqUtil.DSL_CONTEXT
        .select(ID_FIELD)
        .from(MY_TABLE)
        .where(conditionBuilder.build())
        .orderBy(UPDATED_AT.asc())
        .offset(offset.get())
        .limit(limit.get())
        .fetch();

return JooqUtil.toPreparedSql(
    JooqUtil.DSL_CONTEXT
        .select(JooqUtil.createFields(ALL_COLUMN_NAMES))
        .from(MY_TABLE)
        .where(ID_FIELD.in(subquery)));
```

p.s. The reason I'm doing this is due to the orderBy / offset / limit for large offsets (one of the columns I'm selecting is not eligible to be added to the index due to being a blob type, so I cannot create a covering index).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the separate database roundtrip can indeed be avoided. In your case you should be able to simply use the `SELECT` clause of the second query in the first query:

```java
return JooqUtil.toPreparedSql(
    JooqUtil.DSL_CONTEXT
        .select(JooqUtil.createFields(ALL_COLUMN_NAMES))
        .from(MY_TABLE)
        .where(conditionBuilder.build())
        .orderBy(UPDATED_AT.asc())
        .offset(offset.get())
        .limit(limit.get())
);
```

Since your rows have an ID, you may however want to use jOOQ's `SEEK` clause instead of `OFFSET`. I recommend that you read [this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/26/faster-sql-paging-with-jooq-using-the-seek-method/) and [this manual section](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/seek-clause/) which explain what the difference is and why you may want to use `SEEK`.